# Cypress | SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," while parsing file:

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, cypress

I am trying to automate an application developed with React and Sass. This is the xpath I wrote for an element

//span[contains(@class,'BettingAdd__Single ewp79e31')]/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[2]

The automation tool is Cypress. VS code is the editor I'm using for scripting. When I using this xpath and try to execute my script, it gives an error.

```html
Users/Frontend Automation/cypress/integration/examples/silkpath.spec.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (25:42)

  23 | 
  24 |       
> 25 |         cy.xpath('//span[contains(@class,'BettingAdd__Single               ewp79e31')]/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[2]').click();
     |                                           ^
  26 | 
  27 |         })
  28 |          while parsing file: /Users/Frontend Automation/cypress/integration/examples/silkpath.spec.js
GET /__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/examples/silkpath.spec.js 200 0.496 ms - -
GET /sw.js 200 559.189 ms - -
```

Is that mean Cypress can not identfy an xpath like this?
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You need to escape your quotes within the string with `\'`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape that `'` with a `\`:

```
cy.xpath('//span[contains(@class,\'BettingAdd__Single       ewp79e31')]/parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[2]').click();
```

Comment: Thanks Luke '\' worked. But the same error gives from another part of the xpath. How to escape /parent::div/preceding-sibling::div[2]. Try with using \ but didn't work.

I know in Selenium we can use "//" to escape "/". Is there a way to escape "/" and "::" in Cypress when we using relative xpath like this?